# ERROR - Installing Appium in a Spring Boot Project- Maven Dependencies Break

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies, appium

I'm trying to install appium on a Spring boot project - according to here https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/Installing-the-project.md

When running a simple script I got this ERROR:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/internal/Require
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.options.BaseOptions.setCapability(BaseOptions.java:144)
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.options.CanSetCapability.amend(CanSetCapability.java:30)
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.options.BaseOptions.setPlatformName(BaseOptions.java:86)
> at io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options.setCommonOptions(UiAutomator2Options.java:222)
> at io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options.(UiAutomator2Options.java:208)
> at com.aniview.testService.content.initAppium.main(initAppium.java:25)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> ... 6 more

My script:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;



public class initAppium {

static AppiumDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options()
            .setDeviceName("emulator-5554 (sdk_gphone64_arm64 - Android 12)")
            .setUdid("emulator-5554")
            .setPlatformName("Android")
            .setPlatformVersion("12")
            .setChromedriverExecutable("/Users/x/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver")
            .setAppPackage("com.android.chrome")
            .setAppActivity("com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main")
            .setAutoWebview(true)
            .eventTimings();

    driver = new AppiumDriver(url, options);

    System.out.println("Application started");
}
```

}

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.aniview</groupId>
<artifactId>testService</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>testService</name>
<description>Web service for managing test executions</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>18</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.163</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
        <version>v4-rev493-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.33.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.google.guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>1.32.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
        <version>25.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev33-1.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20190722</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I tried to run this script on a fresh new project just with this dependency:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It worked as expected and didn't errored.
I know that java-client contain already selenium libs but I tried to remove them and it still errors.

What I noticed is:
When I adding all my dependencies to the fresh project EXCEPT the spring boot dependencies the fresh project works GOOD. BUT when i adding the 2 dependencies of spring and the parent (spring-boot-starter-parent) it FAILS. So I guess it's something with the spring dependencies maybe specific with the parent dependency.

How can I solve that ?

Environment - Mac, M1 pro, Intelij, Maven, Java 18

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

I found out that `<parent>` tag is overriding the dependencies (in my case "spring-boot-starter-parent" overrode Selenium jars)
So I navigated to ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.6.3/spring-boot-dependencies-2.6.3.pom
changed those:
<selenium.version>4.4.0</selenium.version>
<selenium-htmlunit.version>2.64.0</selenium-htmlunit.version>

Actually I could update my spring-boot to 2.7.2 and it should work as well.